# org.apache.spark.ml.feature.IDF error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

As mentioned in http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{HashingTF, IDF, Tokenizer}
```

Spark displays

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.IDF
<console>:13: error: object IDF is not a member of package org.apache.spark.ml.feature
       import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.IDF
```

Whereas, `import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.IDF` works fine.

Any reasons for the error. I am new to spark and scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that the `feature.IDF` class was introduced into `spark-ml` with spark 1.4. Thus the `object IDF is not a member of package org.apache.spark.ml.feature` error.

You can try to use the spark-mllib IDF class instead.

Comment: Is there any documentation mentioning any reason for putting feature.IDF in spark-ml ?

Comment: IDF is in both spark-mllib and spark-ml in the current version of spark. I invite you to read about the difference between both libraries on the official documentation page.

Comment: The difference is mainly conceptual, spark-ml use spark-mllib under the hood. Spark-ml is more or less s wrapper around spark-mllib that allows the algorithms of spark-mllib to be use directly on DataFrames.

Answer (score 1):

This is not reproducible in `spark-1.4.1`. Which version are you using?

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.IDF
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.IDF

scala> import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{HashingTF, IDF, Tokenizer}
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{HashingTF, IDF, Tokenizer}
```

**EDIT1**

Spark 1.2.x contains only: `org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.IDF`

Try searching for IDF here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.IDF

Comment: Try this `import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.IDF` notice the change from `ml` to `mllib`

Comment: `import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.IDF` works fine. Its already mentioned in the question.

Comment: @AayushKumarSingha see my edits, it explains the reason.